# Retrieving fingerprint data from MySQL and compare it in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, fingerprint

I am using a fingerprint reader called Digital Persona UareU 4500 and its SDK. I was about to insert a fingerprint template (Fmd) into MySQL database as a BLOB. But I have trouble creating a Fmd object again from the MySQL BLOB in order to compare the live read fingerprint with the stored fingerprint template. Can someone help me how to create a Fmd again from the BLOB (java byte[])?

Insert Code:

```
public void saveFingerToDb(Fmd fmd) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement prst = Db.connectDb().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO fingerprint (finger_print) VALUES (?)");
            prst.setBinaryStream(1, new ByteInputStream(fmd.getData(), fmd.getData().length));
            prst.executeUpdate();
            prst.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think this sample code might help you. https://github.com/ankit4u3/Fingerprint-Extract-and-SaveImage

Comment: Can you check if this helps: http://camsunit.com/application/javascript-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html#compare-fingerprint